# Hadoop spilling records from circular buffer (mapper)

Tags: hadoop, compression

So as far as I understand, these mappers have a circular buffer that they keep writing to until a certain threshold is reached, when they decide to spill data to disk. This process may involve running a combiner and compressing data while writing to the disk.

So, I was thinking if instead we could configure to compress the data in memory and store in memory, so that maybe at the end of the mapper it does not have overflown its circular memory and hence only need to spill once to the disk. Is this possible? And/or useful?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible and a useful optimization. It won't work very well with combiners because you will need to decompress the buffer again before writing, so you need to take care that you fallback to the old behaviour if a combiner is defined.